# MySql read DaaDir incorrectly and thus cant access it

Tags: mysql, database

I have just downloaded mySql 5.7 win32 x86 for Windows 10

in "my.ini" I set the following values:

```
basedir="D:\databases\MySQL-5_7(x86)"         
datadir="W:\b-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data"
```

However, if i try open CMD in admin mode and type: mysqld --console

I get errors:

> D:\databases\MySQL-5_7(x86)\bin>mysqld --console mysqld: Can't change
>   dir to 'W-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\' (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument
>   [OS Error Code : 0x7b]) 2017-02-02T23:47:18.575846Z 0 [Warning]
>   TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2017-02-02T23:47:18.575846Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE',
>   'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be
>   used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a
>   future release. 2017-02-02T23:47:18.575846Z 0 [Warning]
>   'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
>   2017-02-02T23:47:18.575846Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to
>   NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
>   2017-02-02T23:47:18.576845Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17) starting
>   as process 11400 ... 2017-02-02T23:47:18.580846Z 0 [Warning] Can't
>   create test file
>   W-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\rd-w-vista.lower-test
>   2017-02-02T23:47:18.581846Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file
>   W-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\rd-w-vista.lower-test
>   2017-02-02T23:47:18.581846Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to
>   W-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\ 2017-02-02T23:47:18.582846Z 0 [ERROR]
>   Aborting
>
> 2017-02-02T23:47:18.583846Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
>   2017-02-02T23:47:18.583846Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> D:\databases\MySQL-5_7(x86)\bin>

However, inspecting the emssage, one can see MySql tries access path **W-databases\MySql** - i.e. it emove the drive part...

How do I solve that and solve res of the errors?

I just want to updae o the new MySql version and continue o use my existing 5.0 db

Comment: It looks like it is interpreting `\b` as a backspace somehow. Try it without the quotes, or with forward slashes, or both.

Comment: Combining the two works! (make i an answer and i will accept it!) However - it could not load/read my old 5.0 database properly - and while I can initialize from fresh I can not solve "2017-02-03T02:52:01.076801Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exis" - I have created a new SO for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016071/mysql-zip-installation-on-windows-and-how-to-fix-missing-mysql-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is interpreting `\b` as a backspace somehow. Try it without the quotes, or with forward slashes, or both.