# MySQL installation on Windows - and how to fix missing mysql.user?

Tags: mysql

I was using an old MySql 5.0 installation. Then decided to get newest 5.7 .zip release.

This is what I have done:

```
mysqld -initialize-insecure
```

(As I intend to use this for localhost/root usage only)

This creates some files in the root of the MySQL data directory.

However, running

```
mysqld --console
```

gives error

> 2017-02-03T02:52:01.076801Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock
>   privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exis

I then intended to move over my two 5.0 databases (each in a subfolder in my old mysql 5.0 "data dir" directory.)

Possibly I could then run *mysql_upgrade* then?

My full error log is here:

> D:\databases\MySQL-5_7(x86)\bin>mysqld --console
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.227754Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit
>   DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2017-02-03T02:52:00.227754Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE',
>   'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be
>   used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a
>   future release. 2017-02-03T02:52:00.227754Z 0 [Warning]
>   'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.227754Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to
>   NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.227754Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17) starting
>   as process 13872 ... 2017-02-03T02:52:00.235754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.236754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.236754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not
>   used 2017-02-03T02:52:00.237754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables
>   use zlib 1.2.3 2017-02-03T02:52:00.237754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
>   pools: 1 2017-02-03T02:52:00.238755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU
>   crc32 instructions 2017-02-03T02:52:00.240755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size
>   = 128M 2017-02-03T02:52:00.249755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 2017-02-03T02:52:00.363762Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.498769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared
>   tablespace for temporary tables 2017-02-03T02:52:00.499769Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
>   file full; Please wait ... 2017-02-03T02:52:00.745783Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB. 2017-02-03T02:52:00.933793Z
>   0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback
>   segment(s) are active. 2017-02-03T02:52:00.934792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32
>   non-redo rollback segment(s) are active. 2017-02-03T02:52:00.936793Z 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 2017-02-03T02:52:00.988797Z
>   0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 1209961
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.988797Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.990797Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s)
>   from W:\b-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\ib_buffer_pool mysqld: Table
>   'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist 2017-02-03T02:52:00.991796Z 0 [ERROR]
>   Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create
>   it. 2017-02-03T02:52:00.993796Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator
>   variables, current_pid: 13872, server_start_time: 1486090320,
>   bytes_sent: 0, 2017-02-03T02:52:00.993796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer
>   pool(s) load completed at 170203  3:52:00 2017-02-03T02:52:00.997796Z
>   0 [Note] Generated uuid: 'bc608dfe-e9bb-11e6-b692-00248c156225',
>   server_start_time: 1486104192, bytes_sent: 361844000
>   2017-02-03T02:52:00.997796Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been
>   found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has
>   been started. Generating a new UUID:
>   bc608dfe-e9bb-11e6-b692-00248c156225. 2017-02-03T02:52:01.041799Z 0
>   [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table
>   'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened. 2017-02-03T02:52:01.041799Z 0
>   [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library
>   error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.043799Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address):
>   '*'; port: 3306 2017-02-03T02:52:01.044802Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is
>   available. 2017-02-03T02:52:01.045801Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to
>   '::'; 2017-02-03T02:52:01.045801Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on
>   IP: '::'. 2017-02-03T02:52:01.054800Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open
>   optimizer cost constant tables
>
> 2017-02-03T02:52:01.076801Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock
>   privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.077801Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2017-02-03T02:52:01.078801Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.079801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.079801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.080801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.081801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.081801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.082801Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.082801Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'MyISAM' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.083801Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.083801Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.084801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.084801Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.085801Z 0
>   [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.087801Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.088802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.089802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.089802Z
>   0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.090802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_TABLES' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.091802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.091802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.092802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_CONFIG' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.093802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.093802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.094802Z 0
>   [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.094802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_METRICS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.095802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.097802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.098802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.099802Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.099802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.100802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.100802Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.101802Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.102802Z 0
>   [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.102802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.103803Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.103803Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.104802Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'INNODB_TRX' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.104802Z 0 [Note] Shutting
>   down plugin 'InnoDB' 2017-02-03T02:52:01.105803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS
>   optimize thread exiting. 2017-02-03T02:52:01.107803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Starting shutdown... 2017-02-03T02:52:01.209808Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Dumping buffer pool(s) to
>   W:\b-databases\MySql\5.0.x\data\ib_buffer_pool
>   2017-02-03T02:52:01.214809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump
>   completed at 170203  3:52:01 2017-02-03T02:52:02.408874Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1209980
>   2017-02-03T02:52:02.408874Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary
>   tablespace data file: "ibtmp1" 2017-02-03T02:52:02.409874Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY' 2017-02-03T02:52:02.410874Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'CSV' 2017-02-03T02:52:02.410874Z 0 [Note]
>   Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password' 2017-02-03T02:52:02.411874Z 0
>   [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:02.412874Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
>   2017-02-03T02:52:02.412874Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

And this is my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=D:/databases/MySQL-5_7(x86)
datadir=W:/b-databases/MySql/5.0.x/data
port=3306
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I got it working now - I redid what was mentioned here and this time the user tables were created as well. Not quite sure why it did not work befoe, but still deserves to be an answer:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

Comment: the page no more exists